# Excel duplicate rows logic

Tags: excel, duplicates

Is there a way to get rid of duplicates ONLY if the next row has the same value.

Example:

I have an excel document with Name and date of birth:

```
person1     
            01/01/01
            01/01/01
person2     
            02/02/02
person3     
            03/03/03
            03/03/03
            03/03/03
```

I have thousands of rows of data.  I cannot use "Remove Duplicates" functions because more than one person can have same date of birth.  Any idea how to fix this data so I can import it in SQL Server?

Comment: You can use remove duplicates with two criteria, but that would mean you need to fill in the person's name into all the empty cells.

Comment: Or simply filter on the empty cells in column A and delete them.

Comment: I think @ScottCraner first suggestion will work and you can easily fill in blank cells with a formula `=IF(Isblank(A2),C1,A2)` starting in C2, where C1 formula is = `A1`

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates, or all duplicate instances? (Meaning, if you have 5 of the same string, do you want to keep just one? or delete doubles, leaving 3?)

Comment: I want to only keep just one instance.  so per each person, one date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

All of you gave me an idea to find a solution.  Here's what I did: I shifted date of birth column one row up so now there is a date of birth per person row.  Then I selected both columns and click on 'Find & Selection' (under Editing) > Go to Special >  selected "Blanks" option and clicked Ok.  Next, under Cells section > Delete > Delete Sheet Rows.  It did the trick.

Comment: good on you, man :) Glad SO could be a catalyst to spark the solution :)